# saving matplotlib animation leads to error

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I created a program (see below) that takes position, force, and time from a pandas dataframe. The goal is to plot position vs force and animate it based on the time data associated with it.

The animation is working well so far but I cannot save the animation, either as a gif or mp4. I have read countless solutions online for this sort of problem but none seem to work.

I am using OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6 and python3.6. I used `brew install ffmpeg` and `brew install mencoder`. For both I get the error

```
 File "animation.py", line 45, in <module>
    ani.save('test.mp4', writer=writer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1009, in save
    for a in all_anim]):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1009, in <listcomp>
    for a in all_anim]):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1482, in new_saved_frame_seq
    return itertools.islice(self.new_frame_seq(), self.save_count)
ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.
```

I used `pip` to install a lot of my other packages, such as pandas, so maybe that is the root of the problem?

Below is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas

TABLE = pandas.read_csv("Data.csv")


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

xs=[]
ys=[]

def animate(interval):

    time = interval

    #convert to TIME series to int for handling purposes
    TABLE.TIME = TABLE.TIME.astype(int)

    if time in TABLE.TIME.unique(): 

        POSIT_series = TABLE[TABLE.TIME == time].POSIT
        POSIT_list = POSIT_series.tolist()
        x = POSIT_list[0]

        FORCE_series = TABLE[TABLE.TIME == time].FORCE
        FORCE_list = FORCE_series.tolist()
        y = FORCE_list[0]

        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs,ys)
    return

FRAMES= TABLE.TIME.astype(int).max()    
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']='/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
writer = animation.FFMpegWriter()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1, frames=FRAMES, repeat=False)
plt.show()

#same error for writer = 'mencoder' and writer ='ffpmeg
ani.save('test.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Data I am practicing on. Eventually I will run this code on a much bigger datafile.

```
TESTNUM,POINTNUM,TIME,POSIT,FORCE,EXT,CH5,CH6,CH7,CH8
1550,1,0.9,0.00055,10.59274006,-0.00382513,,,,
1550,2,1.049,0.0006,10.80716419,0.0001464,,,,
1550,3,1.34,0.00085,12.23668289,-2.749E-05,,,,
1550,4,1.54,0.001,14.26660252,-7.324E-05,,,,
1550,5,1.938,0.001275,15.7961874,0.0001464,,,,
1550,6,3,0.016550001,19.67018318,0.00181191,,,,
1550,7,4,0.016625,30.94909668,0.00188507,,,,
1550,8,5,0.0167,25.63127708,0.00183932,,,,
1550,9,6,0.016799999,18.42650795,0.00197664,,,,
1550,10,7,0.016925,16.52525139,0.00201322,,,,
1550,11,8,0.017774999,18.09771156,0.00226945,,,,
1550,12,9,0.018300001,19.49864578,0.00216879,,,,
1550,13,10,0.019099999,21.24265671,0.0022237,,,,
1550,14,11,0.019424999,22.77224159,0.0022237,,,,
1550,15,12,0.0197,24.18746758,0.00225112,,,,
1550,16,13,0.019974999,26.23167801,0.00224203,,,,
```

Comment: What happens if you set the `save_count` argument manually: `FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1, frames=FRAMES, repeat=False, save_count=FRAMES)` ?

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: FYI images generally aren't a good way to present data, I would suggest CSV format so it's easy to copy-paste.

Comment: ok. now presenting the data in csv format.

Comment: The code runs fine for me and I'm almost out of ideas. You haven't reported about your matplotlib version yet, could it be that it is very old? Next: What happens if you change the backend: above the very first line of the code paste `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`. A final idea: Make a backup of your animation.py and above the line "line 1482", which causes the error, `print(self.save_count)`. See how often and what that prints.

Comment: I upgraded matplotlib to Version 2.0.2 and I am still getting the same error albeit on a different line (line 1532 instead of line 1482). import `matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` did not seem to do the trick either.  When you say write `print(self.save_count)` above line 1482 did you mean to write this code in the matplotlib package?

Comment: The code runs fine for you? Are you using ffmpeg as the moviewriter? If so can you tell me how you installed ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug - see here http://bugs.python.org/issue30537. Essentially, numpy ints are not a sub-class of python ints and this eventually leads to a problem in this case.

As a workaround, I've modified the animation.py code by adding 
self.save_count = int(self.save_count) at the start of this function (see below). This changes the type of self.save_count from 'numpy.int64' to 'int' and the animation now saves correctly.  I'm going to flag this as an issue at matplotlib.

```
def new_saved_frame_seq(self):
    # Generate an iterator for the sequence of saved data. If there are
    # no saved frames, generate a new frame sequence and take the first
    # save_count entries in it.
    self.save_count = int(self.save_count)
    print(type(self.save_count))

    if self._save_seq:
        # While iterating we are going to update _save_seq
        # so make a copy to safely iterate over
        self._old_saved_seq = list(self._save_seq)
        return iter(self._old_saved_seq)
    else:
        return itertools.islice(self.new_frame_seq(), self.save_count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This bug has been driving me crazy. I'm confused where exactly I should put this function though. Is it its own function and if so where should I call it? Or am I supposed to modify the function `animate` to include `self.save_count = int(self.save_count)` and the other logic statement?

Comment: Ok. Finally got it to work! I realized that you wanted me to go into matplotlib package itself and update the 'animation.py' script. There seemed to be two instances of the 'new_saved_frame_seq' function. I updated the second instance with the code above. I then reran my code and did not get an error. However, only the last frame of the animation was saved to the 'test.mp4' file. I deleted the `plt.show` line from my script and now everything works fine.

Comment: Great - I've submitted a pull request to matplotlib with this fix:https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8984